# How to read Azure Service Bus Topic Name contains / in it. eg: xxx/t000 in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, servicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am using PowerShell to read the Azure Service Bus Topics. The topic name contains some special characters in it. Eg. Topic name is xxx/t000.

When I use:

```
Get-AzureRmServiceBusSubscription -ResourceGroup 'rg_name' -NamespaceName 'sbname' -TopicName "xxx/t000"
```

I am getting error:

> Operation returned an invalid Status code "Not Found"

So I am predicting the issue with the / in the topic name.
Can someone help me on how to read the topic name which contains "/" in it?

Comment: Have you tried `xxx\/t000`?

Comment: I have tried it before.Still the same issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the topic name in single quotes.

```
-TopicName 'xxx/t000'
```

Comment: I tried with the single quote.But still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to Azure Resource Manager, which doesn't support resource names that have "/". You should be able to reference the topic by replacing '/' with '~'.

Here's a good behind the scenes description about this subject on MSDN: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2017/06/21/azure-service-bus-azure-resource-manager-and-this-character/

> On the Service Bus side we will convert "/" to "~" when interfacing
>   with ARM, but retain the slashes in our back-end so things continue to
>   work the way they are supposed to.